# kafka consumer can't get previous unconsumed event

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer, consumer

**Step 1:** create Topic with only one partition:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

**Step 2:** Produce some message to topic `test`.

**Step 3:** Start a consume on topic `test`. It can get all messages which is pushed in Step 2.

It works fine with topic with 1 partition.

But when I try to use topic with 2 partitions, consumer only get messages which are generated after the consumer is up.

Reproduce:

**Step 1:** create Topic with only one partition:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test2`

**Step 2:** Produce some message to topic `test2`.

**Step 3:** Start a consumer on topic `test2`. It can't get messages in Step 2.

**Step 4:** keep consumer on, produce some message to topic `test2`, then now the consumer can get messages.

Does it work fine? Or I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

auto.offset.reset option's default value is 'latest'

If you want to read the message that was sent before the consumer
set auto.offset.reset:earliest